# How to prove that support of $u_{r}$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry

Let's  ${u_r}:{\mathbb{R}^k}\to{\mathbb{R}}$,  $\varphi \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,  $Jf$ ( jacobian of $f$, with $f: \mathbb{R}^{k}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ Lipschitz ), and $\chi_E$ (characteristic function on $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$  where $E$ borel bounded subset),
\begin{equation*}
    u_r(w) := \chi_E(z+rw)\varphi\Bigl(\frac{f(z+ rw)-f(z)}{r}\Bigr) J f(z+rw).
\end{equation*}

Statement: there are $ r_0> 0 $ and $ R> 0 $ such that $ supp(u_{r}) \subset \mathbb{B}(0,R) $ for $ r \in (0, r_{0}) $.

My attempt:  
In fact, since $ f $ is derivable into $z$ and $ Jf(z)> 0 $, there are $ s_{0},  \lambda > 0 $ such that
\begin{equation}
    |{f(z')-f(z)}| \geq \lambda ||{z'-z}||
\end{equation}
for every $ z '\in \mathbb{B}(z,s_{0}) $. On the other hand, if $ \rho> 0 $ is such that $ supp (\varphi) \subset  \mathbb{B}(0,\rho) $, then
\begin{equation*}
    |{f(z+rw) -f(z)}|\leq r\rho
\end{equation*}
for all  $w\in supp(u_{r})$. Hence, if $ w \in supp(u_{r}) $ with $ r < s_{0} / \rho $,  you have $ z + rw \in \mathbb{B}(z,s_{0}) $, so $ r \rho \geq  |{f (z + rw) -f (z)}| \geq \lambda ||{z + rw-z}|| = \lambda r ||{w}|| $, then $ ||{w}|| \leq \rho / \lambda $, which proves statement with $ r_{0}: = s_{0} / \rho $ and $ R: = \rho / \lambda $.

I'm not sure what  $ z + rw \in \mathbb{B}(z,s_{0}) $ , I really appreciate it if someone could give me an idea how to improve this argument.

Another idea that I had, was to prove that the $supp(u_{0})$ is compact, which I did, in order to arrive at that the $supp(u_{r})$ is compact, which would be another way to conclude that statement in another way. But unfortunately I could not find that relationship between the $supp(u_{0})$ and the $supp(u_{r}) $I really appreciate the attention given.

Comment: Clearly, $\{x | u_r(x) \neq 0\} \subseteq E$ since $\chi_E$ is a factor of $u_r$. Thus, $supp(u_r) \subseteq$ the closure of $E$. Since $E$ is bounded, its closure is also bounded. Thus, the support of $u_r$ is bounded. And since supports are always closed, the support of $u_r$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks  a lot @MarkSaving. It was really helpful your comment.

Comment: Hello, I have not finished the exercise yet, because I would need to prove that there is $ r_0> 0 $ such that the supports of the $ u_r $ are contained in the same compact for $ 0 <r <r_ {0} $. For this reason I feel that if I better go for the first idea I had, that is, if I manage to fix the part where $  +  \in \mathbb {B} (, _ {0}) $, I can solve my problem of a faster way. I would appreciate a lot if you can help me @MarkSaving.